# Image/Text floating not working

Tags: php

I'm currently working for a program that creates business card, it's almost done except for the image/text floating. I'm using container fluid to make my panels viewed side by side but my problem is in the right side I have a preview of the actual business card but the text won't go on the right side of the logo. I almost tried everything that I can found in internet like float, clear and setting the right axis manually, but it doesn't work. I need help! Please. This is the actual image(the one I'm trying to fix)

[image]

Here's my code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="card">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url('My_account/do_create_businesscard'); ?>" method="post">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="pname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Fullname</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Fullname" value="<?php echo strtoupper($empInfo->firstname).' '. substr($empInfo->middlename,0,1).'. '.  strtoupper($empInfo->lastname);?>" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="sg" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Position and Section</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $empInfo->position_name;?> <?php echo $empInfo->section_name;?>" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="sg" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Division</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $empInfo->division_name;?>" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="sg" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Department</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="FOREIGN SERVICE INSTITUTE" readonly><br><input type="text" class="form-control" value="DEPARTMENT OF FOREIGN AFFAIRS" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="sg" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Address</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="5/F DFA Bldg., 2330 Roxas Blvd." readonly><br><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Pasay City 1300, Philippines" readonly>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="pname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Telephone No.</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9" id="telno">
                                            <input type="number" name="txttelno" class="form-control" id="txttelno" min="0" required>
                                            <input type="number" name="txttelno1" class="form-control" id="txttelno1">
                                            <!-- <button type="button"  id="add_button_tel"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>  -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                      <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="pname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Fax No.</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9" id="faxno">
                                            <input type="number" name="txtfaxno" class="form-control" id="txtfaxno" min="0" required>
                                            <!-- <button type="button"  id="add_button_fax"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>  -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                     <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="pname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Mobile No.</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9" id="mobileno">
                                            <input type="number" name="txtmobileno" class="form-control" id="txtmobileno"  min="0" required>
                                            <input type="number" name="txtmobileno1" class="form-control" id="txtmobileno1">
                                            <!-- <button type="button"  id="add_button_mob"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>  -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="pname" class="col-sm-3 text-right control-label col-form-label">Email</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9" id="email">
                                            <input type="email" name="txtemail" class="form-control" id="txtemail" value="<?php echo $empInfo->email;?>" required>
                                            <input type="text" name="txtemail1" class="form-control" id="txtemail1">
                                            <!-- <button type="button"  id="add_button_em"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>  -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                <div class="border-top">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create Business Card</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
            </div>
</div>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        div .all {
            clear: both;
        }
        div .text {
            right: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>



                    <div class="col-5">
                        <h2>Business Card Preview</h2>
                        <div class="card" style=" width:100%; border: 2px solid Black;">
                            <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/fsilogo.jpg')?>" style="float:left;width: 15%; height: 15%;">
                            <div class="text">
                                <div id="fullnamecontainer"><b>
                                    <?php echo strtoupper($empInfo->firstname).' '. substr($empInfo->middlename,0,1).'. '.  strtoupper($empInfo->lastname);?></b>
                                </div>
                                <div id="posseccontainer">
                                   <b><?php echo $empInfo->position_name.' '. $empInfo->section_name;?></b>
                                </div>

                                <div id="divcontainer">
                                   <b><?php echo $empInfo->division_name;?></b>
                                </div>

                                <div id="deptcontainer">
                                   <b><?php echo "FOREIGN SERVICE INSTITUTE <br> DEPARTMENT OF FOREIGN AFFAIRS"?></b>
                                </div>

                                <div id="addcontainer">
                                   <b><?php echo "5/F DFA Bldg., 2330 Roxas Blvd. <br> Pasay City 1300, Philippines"?></b>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <b>Tel. No.: <span id="showtelno"></span>
                                    <br>
                                    <span id="showtelno1"></span></b>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <b>Fax No.: <span id="showfaxno"></span></b>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <b>Mobile No.: <span id="showmobno"></span>
                                    <br>
                                    <span id="showmobno1"></span></b>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <b>Email:<span id="showemail"> <?php echo $empInfo->email;?></span>
                                    <br>
                                    <span id="showemail1"></span></b>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?>
```

Comment: have your img tag in a separate div with classes such as col-md-* and your text wrapper div with class col-md-*. Also use all the col-xs-*, col-sm-*,col-lg-*

Comment: I tried using col-md but the text and image got stacked.

Comment: Joana img in col-md-4 and text as col-md-8. Bootstrap uses 12 grid layout.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
div .text {
        float:right;
    }
```

Comment: can you upload the code to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) so that i may take a look at it precisely.

Comment: I already fix the error, the main div should be in the row class. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct code.

```
<div class="col-5">
                        <h2>Business Card Preview</h2>
                        <div class="card">
                        <div class="col-md-12" style=" width:100%; border: 2px solid Black;">


                            <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-md-3"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/fsilogo.jpg')?>" width="120"></div> 

                                  <div class="col-md-9" style="float: right;" >
                                <div id="fullnamecontainer"><b>
                                    <?php echo strtoupper($empInfo->firstname).' '. substr($empInfo->middlename,0,1).'. '.  strtoupper($empInfo->lastname);?></b>
                                </div>
                                <div id="posseccontainer">
                                   <b><?php echo $empInfo->position_name.' '. $empInfo->section_name;?></b>
                                </div>

                                <div id="divcontainer">
                                   <b><?php echo $empInfo->division_name;?></b>
                                </div>

                                <div id="deptcontainer">
                                   <b><?php echo "FOREIGN SERVICE INSTITUTE <br> DEPARTMENT OF FOREIGN AFFAIRS"?></b>
                                </div>

                                <div id="addcontainer">
                                   <b><?php echo "5/F DFA Bldg., 2330 Roxas Blvd. <br> Pasay City 1300, Philippines"?></b>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <b>Tel. No.: <span id="showtelno"></span>
                                    <b>/</b>
                                    <span id="showtelno1"></span></b>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <b>Fax No.: <span id="showfaxno"></span></b>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <b>Mobile No.: <span id="showmobno"></span>
                                    <b>/</b>
                                    <span id="showmobno1"></span></b>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <b>Email:<span id="showemail"> <?php echo $empInfo->email;?></span>
                                    <b>/</b>
                                    <span id="showemail1"></span></b>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>





                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>


</div>
```

- The main div that holds the image and the text should be in the row class.